# Getting empty graph with this code in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote the code like down below and i get blank graph. However, i want to obtain 4 plots for Open, High, Low, Close. How can i fix the code?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax=plt.subplots()

Levels = ['Open','High','Low','Close']
financial_data = (('3 October 2016',774.25,776.065002,769.5,772.559998),
('4',776.030029,778.710022,772.890015,776.429993),
('5',779.309998,782.070007,775.650024,776.469971),
('6',779,780.47998,775.539978,776.859985),
('7',779.659973,779.659973,770.75,775.080017),)
Days, Open, High, Low, Close= zip(*financial_data)
Position= list(range(len(financial_data)))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the reason you have no graph data showing is that there are no function calls to a "plt.plot(.....)" function (or functions) prior to the the "plt.show()" call.

I don't know what type of graph/chart style you are looking for (scatter chart, bar chart, line chart, etc.) so I took the liberty to generate a multiline chart with your data.  Following is a snippet of code utilizing your data to produce a line chart.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xdate  = ['3 October 2016', '4 October 2016', '5 October 2016', '6 October 2016', '7 October 2016']
yopen  = [774.25, 776.030029, 779.309998, 779, 779.659973]
yhigh  = [776.065002, 778.710022, 782.070007, 780.47998, 779.659973]
ylow   = [769.5, 772.890015, 775.650024, 775.539978, 770.75]
yclose = [772.559998, 776.429993, 776.469971, 776.859985, 776.859985]

plt.plot(xdate, yopen,  label = "Open")
plt.plot(xdate, yhigh,  label = "High")
plt.plot(xdate, ylow,   label = "Low")
plt.plot(xdate, yclose, label = "Close")
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

This resulted in a multiline graph.

[image: Sample Chart]

As I noted, I don't know exactly what type of chart you are after, but I think this might provide a springboard for continuing on with your coding effort.

Hope that helps.

Regards.

Comment: If we want to use the zip function, how should we write the code?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have experience with the zip function.  You might have to see if others comment on that.  Regards.